# Create topic from Consumer side

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I'm not sure whether its possible or not. But I want to ask here becasue could not find any relevant resource online.

Is that possible, I could create topic from the consumer side ?

Usually we create consumers to access existing topics in broker. (Created at broker level)

But is there any way, I could create topic and then consume it ? This all work I want to do it on consumer side configuration. First create `if not exists` and then consume it.

Is that possible or its not a valid question ?

Comment: I don't think so. What kind of API would be involved with a consumer configuring the broker, and how would it work? Presumably, it would be the same API you use to create the topic at the broker level. Perhaps you want to trigger that from the consumer, so you create a topic on the broker and... what's going to publish messages to the topic?

Comment: Yes Its a same API, ApacheKafka. I was thinking If is there any config which could be set at broker level so that consumer group could create topic on its own and consume messages.

Comment: Messages from the aether presumably. Was I don't think so too vague?

Comment: :) Publishing event messages in XML type generated from web application.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it it's possible by triggering an Exception. If the consumer will try to connect to the topic and wasn't created you can launch a function that create an [`AdminClient`](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html) where you can create a topic.

But you still need to fill it so you can maybe create a thread with Worker(Source + Task for xml) and fill your topic with it (in the same function)!

Here the creation of a topic with `AdminCLient` :

```java
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ALLOW_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_CONFIG, true);
        Admin adminClient = Admin.create(properties);
        adminClient.createTopics(Collections.singleton(new NewTopic( {Topic name}, 1, (short) 1)));
```

Hope it was helpfull